# Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8' Cannot parse result path string

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, gradle

Whenever i try to run my app in release or build mode i get the following error

```
[   +2 ms] Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libapp.so, libflutter.so.
[  +97 ms] > Task :app:extractReleaseNativeSymbolTables
[   +1 ms] Unable to extract native debug metadata from D:\flutter\MyApps\quelib_app\build\app\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\arm64-v8a\libapp.so because
unable to locate the objcopy executable for the arm64-v8a ABI.
[   +1 ms] Unable to extract native debug metadata from D:\flutter\MyApps\quelib_app\build\app\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\arm64-v8a\libflutter.so
because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the arm64-v8a ABI.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
> Multiple build operations failed.
      Cannot parse result path string: 
      Cannot parse result path string: 
      Cannot parse result path string: 
      Cannot parse result path string: 
      Cannot parse result path string: 
      Cannot parse result path string: 
      Cannot parse result path string: 
      Cannot parse result path string: 
      Cannot parse result path string: 
      Cannot parse result path string: 
      ...and 3 more failures.
   > Cannot parse result path string: 
   > Cannot parse result path string: 
   > Cannot parse result path string: 
   > Cannot parse result path string: 
   > Cannot parse result path string: 
   > Cannot parse result path string: 
   > Cannot parse result path string: 
   > Cannot parse result path string: 
   > Cannot parse result path string: 
   > Cannot parse result path string: 
   > Cannot parse result path string: 
   > Cannot parse result path string: 
   > Cannot parse result path string: 

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22m 7s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                         1330.6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

And this started after my laptop accidently turned off while building in background. It runs ok in debug mode but not release mode

```
//Flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.8.0 at D:\flutter\Sdk\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision cf44000065 (9 weeks ago), 2021-12-08 14:06:50 -0800
    • Engine revision 40a99c5951
    • Dart version 2.15.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0-rc2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\bright\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0-rc2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[X] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at .\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin version 44.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] VS Code (version 1.64.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\bright\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.34.0

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Infinix X652A (mobile) • 0494625032002068 • android-arm64  • Android 9 (API 28)
    • Edge (web)             • edge             • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 97.0.1072.69

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

am using

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-all.zip
```

I have tried deleting .gradle folder, invalidate & caches in android studio still nothing. Please how do i fix this. If you need more explanation or code please tell me

```
//--stacktrace
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 11 busy and 2 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :app
WARNING:: DSL element 'useProguard' is obsolete.
It will be removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
Use 'android.enableR8' in gradle.properties to switch between R8 and Proguard.

The Kotlin Gradle plugin was loaded multiple times in different subprojects, which is not supported and may break the build.
This might happen in subprojects that apply the Kotlin plugins with the Gradle 'plugins { ... }' DSL if they specify explicit versions, even if the versions are equal.
Please add the Kotlin plugin to the common parent project or the root project, then remove the versions in the subprojects.
If the parent project does not need the plugin, add 'apply false' to the plugin line.
See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl
The Kotlin plugin was loaded in the following projects: ':flutter_image_compress', ':fluttertoast', ':search_choices'

> Task :audioplayers:compileReleaseKotlin
e: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.pom.java.LanguageLevel.<clinit>(LanguageLevel.java:25)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.core.CoreLanguageLevelProjectExtension.<init>(CoreLanguageLevelProjectExtension.java:26)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.core.JavaCoreProjectEnvironment.<init>(JavaCoreProjectEnvironment.java:42)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreProjectEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreProjectEnvironment.kt:26)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$ProjectEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:121)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:425)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:226)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:152)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:386)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:110)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:286)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl$rebuild(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:99)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:114)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:74)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:607)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1659)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected void java.util.ResourceBundle.setParent(java.util.ResourceBundle) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @76a3e297
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtil.java:252)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.getDeclaredMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:269)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.DynamicBundle.<clinit>(DynamicBundle.java:22)
        ... 38 more


> Task :audioplayers:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':audioplayers:compileReleaseKotlin'.
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':audioplayers:compileReleaseKotlin'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$3(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:268)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:184)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:173)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:72)



* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 19m 48s
375 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 369 up-to-date
```